# MVC Model Validation Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-validation

Is there some kind of `OnModelValidating` event in MVC? Or is there another way to run some code during the model validation process?

Comment: Create a class that inherits from [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and override its `OnPropertyValidating` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Its great that you are so helpful, but why don't you post your answers as answers instead of comments?